# How I can call NuxtServerInit correctly?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

When i try to call rest api with nuxtServerInit on Vuex store it don't call, but if call rest api on components or page it works.

store/index.js

```
 import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  news: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_NEWS(state, posts) {
    state.news = posts
  }
}


export const actions = {
 async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, ctx) {
   const res = await axios.get('https://api/news.json')
      commit('SET_NEWS', res.data)
  },
}

export const getters = {
  getNews(state) {
    return state.news
  }
}
```

pages/news/index.vue

```
computed: {
 getNews() {
  return this.$store.getters.getNews
 }
}
```

Comment: What `mode` is Nuxt configured as?

Comment: @tony19 default: universal, ssr false

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your API like this in your vuex actions:

```
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
        const res = (await this.$axios.$get('https://api/news.json')).data
        commit('SET_NEWS', res)
    },
}
```